# When are you "done" with a realm?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, realm

I am currently working on a project with Expo and Realm. I want to integrate Realm into my App, but I don't quite get the line:

> It is important to remember to call the close() method **when done
> with a realm** instance to avoid memory leaks.

*-> https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/open-and-close-a-realm/#close-a-realm*

**I mean: what is the definition of being done?** As soon as my app is closed or as soon as I fetch the data I wanted to? Or should I open and close the realm all the time a user changes an entry?

I already did a lot of research and I know that it it quite expensive (resource wise) to start a new realm on a thread. But if there is already a realm running (UI Thread for Listeners) it isn't cost expensive at all.

**Guess I am not sure on how to use realm within my code correctly.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is widely depends on your use case. Sometimes it can be a lifetime of a screen (you add a new object in a database) or a lifetime of a feature (sequence of the user registration screens).
In general try to avoid multiple calls to open Realm. For example, if you want to create multiple objects it's better

```
open Realm
in transaction {
    in loop {
        create object
    }
}
close Realm
```

Rather than

```
in loop {
    open Realm
    in transaction {
        create object
    }
    close Realm
}
```

If you need more precise answer you can add more details to your question.

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for your reply. Guess I found a solution for my question: I should have a Realm Instance in my App.js (for UI Purposes) which is created in an UseEffect (which will create on start and destroy on End of the App.js Lifecycle) and multiple smaller Realm Instaces that are created and destroyed based on the behavior of my user (adding new entries or deleting them).

Do you think this is a right approach?